# Stochastic process for interest rates allowing negative values

Tags: interest-rates

The Cox-Ingersoll-Ross process for the short term interest rate r(t) does not allow r(t) to become negative, but short-term rates are negative in much of the developed world. To account for this, do you use a CIR process for a shadow rate r'(t) that equals r(t) + c, where c = 0.01 if you think short-term rates cannot get more negative than 1%? Has there been research on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, people have looked into that alreaday, for instance [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25207/extensions-of-cir) and [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43785/shifted-log-normal-model) (for lognormal models). Brigo and Mercurio took the CIR short rate $(x_t)$ and added a deterministic shift $\vartheta(t)$ to it in order to obtain the short rate  process $(r_t)$ via $r_t=x_t+\vartheta(t)$. The function $\vartheta$ serves to guarantee a perfect fit with observed discount factors and hence, can lead to negative short rate. [In their book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C31l_fs-mMkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brigo%20mercurio%20interest%20rate%20models&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_1s3Eo9DjAhVTShUIHVkbAD0Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=brigo%20mercurio%20interest%20rate%20models&f=false), you can read about their CIR extension (named CIR++) in Section 3.9 which addresses the issue of positivity explicitly in 3.9.3.

Note that normally distributed short rate models like the models from Vasicek, Ho-Lee and Hull-White allow directly for negative short rates.